# Saving Graph Message into .MSG or .EML file

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am working on using MS Graph

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/{folderID}/messages/{messageID}
```

to extract email messages. I have a requirement to save the email (message, attachments, etc) into a .MSG or .EML format.

I am having trouble finding anything that can help me do this. Any ideas? I know I can get the MIME value but not sure if that is enough or I need to do more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to save a Message in the MSG file format as this is an Office file format (Compound Binary format https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-cfb/53989ce4-7b05-4f8d-829b-d08d6148375b)

For EML yes all you need is the MIMEContent

```
GET /users/{id}/messages/{id}/$value
```

And save that as a file with .eml extension

That said the MIME content of the message doesn't provide full fidelity on the Message as it won't include any extended MAPI properties. But this is generally only important for Mail Migration and Backup type applications for general use EML should be fine

Comment: Is this still the case?

Comment: Yes the Graph won't give you the msg format